# Estimating gas limit using Go-ethereum BoundContract (abigen)

Tags: go-ethereum, abi

I have a smart contract and it's [native bindings](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/dapp/native-bindings) generated in go-ethereum (version 1.9.11 if that matters) abigen. Im looking for a way to estimate gas limit before calling method on smart contract.

I cannot find anywhere in documentation any way to estimate gas usage of transaction other than providing raw message which seems to defeat purpose of having bindings in the first place.

For now I figured out this:

```go
//error handling removed for brevity
//contracts.MyContractABI is from abigen file.
abi, _ := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(contracts.MyContractABI))
data, _ := abi.Pack("myFunction", myParam, myParam2)

ethRPCParams := ethereum.CallMsg{
    From:     from,
    To:       contractAddr,
    Value:    big.NewInt(0),
    Data:     data,
}
gas, _ := c.ethClient.EstimateGas(context.Background(), ethRPCParams)
```

but it seems to be workaround to instantiate abi separately from already existing and instantiated one in BoundContract.

So, my question is what is the proper way to tackle this operation. For example here I don't get data type safety when estimating gas price and I have to re-instantiate something that should be already instantiated, code is less readable etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NoSend option](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/38ea7f2cf460fb12a5769f8c0767726334111b99) was added to TransactOpts. Maybe just what you need.